# Using FullCalendar how can I adjust the height of the fc-event div?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to display some events, but it is clipping the name of the event in week and day mode.

It appears fullcalendar is setting the height of the fc-event div to 12px, but I need it to be 20px:

```
<div class="fc-event fc-event-skin fc-event-vert fc-corner-top fc-corner-bottom" 
style="position: absolute; z-index: 8; top: 314px; left: 441px; 
background-color: green; color: white; 
width: 112.94999999999999px; height: 12px;  ">
```

Is it possible to set the height of the fc-event div?

Answer (score 5):

e.g.

> .fc-event {    height: 2em; }

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, because any css class definitions are overridden by the "style" attribute that fullcalendar programmatically adds to the <div class="fc-event"> tag.

Comment: .fc-event{  height: 2em !important;} would prevent it from being overrided

Answer (score 5):

I simply figured it out. Just put the important rule in fullcalendar.css

> height: 50px !important;

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It may work if you go into the fullcalendar.css and change the heights.

Comment: I'm sorry, this won't work because the "style" attribute overrides any values set in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is more of a work-around for the issue than an actual solution.
When setting the events, add \r\n in the title attribute to space it out a bit more.

I spent a bit of time going through the js file to try and adjust how the height is calculated, but due to the switching of views, it got a bit messy.

This will increase the height of the event without messing around with the positioning/css.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
        height: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your fullcalendar.min.js change the `defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:15:00"` to whatever the time you required.