# fullcalendar month view how to change the format display

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

How can I change the display format in fullcalendar?
Instead of show the events, want to show a dot or something else!
only in month view!

Similar to below sample from an other script :

[image: sample of dots]

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the css for the event div defined in `fullcalendar.css` file.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990300/using-fullcalendar-how-can-i-adjust-the-height-of-the-fc-event-div) has an example of how to do that to customize the event height.