# How to remove query string from a url?

Tags: python, url

I have the following URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301?aaa=aaa
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990300?fr=aladdin
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375#6
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375#3_1
```

I need URLs for example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990300
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375
```

My attempt:

```
url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301?aaa=aaa'
if '?' in url:
    url=url.split('?')[0]
if '#' in url:
    url = url.split('#')[0]
```

I think this is a stupid way

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The very helpful library [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl) makes it trivial to remove both query and fragment parts:

```
>>> furl.furl("https://hi.com/?abc=def#ghi").remove(args=True, fragment=True).url
https://hi.com/
```

Comment: Why download this library when the builtin Python way is basically exactly the same: `from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit` then `urlunsplit(urlsplit("https://hi.com/?abc=def#ghi")._replace(query="", fragment=""))`

Answer (score 7):

You can split on something that doesn't exist in the string, you'll just get a list of one element, so depending on your goal, you could do something like this to simplify your existing code:

```
url = url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0]
```

Not saying this is the best way (furl is a great solution), but it is a way.

Answer (score 4):

In your example you're also removing [the fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) ([the thing after a `#`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)), not just [the query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

You can remove both by using [`urllib.parse.urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit), then calling [`._replace`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) on the `namedtuple` it returns and converting back to a string URL with [`urllib.parse.unsplit`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit):

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

def remove_query_params_and_fragment(url):
    return urlunsplit(urlsplit(url)._replace(query="", fragment=""))
```

Output:

```
>>> remove_query_params_and_fragment("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301?aaa=aaa")
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301'
>>> remove_query_params_and_fragment("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990300?fr=aladdin")
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990300'
>>> remove_query_params_and_fragment("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375#6")
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375'
>>> remove_query_params_and_fragment("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375?")
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375'
>>> remove_query_params_and_fragment("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375#3_1")
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301?aaa=aaa",
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990300?fr=aladdin",
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375#6",
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375"?,
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375#3_1"]

urls_without_query = [url.split('?')[0] for url in urls]
```

for example, `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301?aaa=aaa".split()` returns a list that looks like `["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301", "aaa=aaa"]`, and if that string is `url`, `url.split('?')[0]` would give you `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301"`.

Edit: I didn't think about `#` arguments. The other answers might help you more :)

Comment: This does not remove fragments, and is not better than the solution the OP is looking to improve upon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [w3lib](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.url_query_cleaner)

```
from w3lib import url as w3_url
url_without_query = w3_url.url_query_cleaner(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using standard libraries, and which parses the URL properly:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'http://www.example.com/this/category?one=two'
parsed = urlparse(url)
print("".join([parsed.scheme,"://",parsed.netloc,parsed.path]))
```

expected output:

`http://www.example.com/this/category`

Note: this also strips params and the fragment, but is easy to modify to include those if you want.